# Python CiscoConfParse. How to get full block by command in middle?

Tags: python, cisco, ciscoconfparse

I need to get full config of block by some command in middle.
In the following example, I got an incomplete block where more indented children 'ip 10.2.2.1' were missing.

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
from pprint import pprint

config = """
hostname switch
interface Vlan2
  description vlan2
  ip address 10.2.2.3/24
  hsrp 2
    ip 10.2.2.1
interface Vlan3
  description vlan3
  ip address 10.3.3.3/24
  hsrp 3
    ip 10.3.3.1
""".splitlines()
ccp = CiscoConfParse(config=config)
blocks = ccp.find_blocks("10.2.2.3/24")
print(blocks)  # ['interface Vlan2', '  description vlan2', '  ip address 10.2.2.3/24', '  hsrp 2']
```

Help me to find elegant way to get next output (with 'ip 10.2.2.1')

```
['interface Vlan2', '  description vlan2', '  ip address 10.2.2.3/24', '  hsrp 2', 'ip 10.2.2.1']
```

Comment: Please [refer to `ciscoconfparse`'s tutorial](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/tutorial_parent_child.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CiscoConfParse 1.9.37...

```py
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

config = """
hostname switch
interface Vlan2
  description vlan2
  ip address 10.2.2.3/24
  hsrp 2
    ip 10.2.2.1
interface Vlan3
  description vlan3
  ip address 10.3.3.3/24
  hsrp 3
    ip 10.3.3.1
""".splitlines()

ccp = CiscoConfParse(config=config)

# Find '10.2.2.3/24' and then recurse back to the interface object...
intfobj = ccp.find_objects("10.2.2.3/24")[0].all_parents[0]
# Buld a list of the parent interface plus all its children
intf_list = [intfobj]
intf_list.extend(intfobj.all_children)

# Use recurse=True to search through multiple child levels...
#    Use \d to ensure that you select the HSRP address instead of 'ip address'
addrobj = ccp.find_child_objects(intfobj.text, "ip\s+\d\S+", recurse=True)[0]
hsrp_addr = addrobj.re_match("ip (\S.+)")
print(hsrp_addr)
print("")
print([ii.text for ii in intf_list])
```

This prints:

```
10.2.2.1

['interface Vlan2', '  description vlan2', '  ip address 10.2.2.3/24', '  hsrp 2', '    ip 10.2.2.1']
```

To get the full block of children, just use `all_children` on that object...

You should avoid `find_blocks()`, it's part of the old API which I will deprecate in version 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
for block in ccp.find_objects_w_child("interface", "ip address 10.2.2.3/24"):  # find interfaces with this ip
    # Print block line and all children
    print([c.text for c in (block, *block.all_children)])
```

seems to do the trick.
I think there could be a simpler way to print out a block and its children, but I'm not familiar with the `ciscoconfparse` API that intimately.

Comment: His question was a little tricky... you have to find the entire interface block from a string in the middle ('10.2.2.3/24')... because of this, you can't assume he knows the interface text at the beginning of the exercise (and thus, you can't use `find_objects_w_child()`).